# Get ALL content between two tags in a string

Tags: php, string, function

I am using a custom PHP function I found on SO. The function's purpose is to find the contents in between to tags and the I replace them with `str_ireplace`. Here is the function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = stripos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = stripos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

I recently found out that when I call the function, it only finds the first occurrence. I.e I want it to find all all things in between every `<tag>` and `</tag>`, yet it only finds the content between the first `<tag>` and `</tag>`. May someone help?

Comment: `stripos()` takes an argument saying where to start looking. So write a loop that keeps searching starting at the end of the previous match.

Comment: Another option is to create a regular expression that matches everything between `$start` and `$end`. Then you can use `preg_match_all()`. Remember to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible you could show me an example? I am new to PHP.

Comment: What are you using this for? Are you handling HTML? If so, consider using an HTML parser (tool built exactly for jobs of this kind).

Comment: There's already an example in your code. See the `$ini` argument in the second `stripos()` call.

Comment: El_Vanja, I am parsing user input similar to BBcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function I've written some months ago for exactly this issue. You'd have to call the function several times with the offset according to the returned $pos in order to get all accurances. I hope that's acceptable.

```
/* getSubstring
   returns a substring between string_before and string_after,
   starts to search at the offset. character of source
   returns an array: ['text'] = string found
                     ['pos'] = starting position of string_before within source
   returns text = '' and pos = false if string is not found
   example: $key = get_substring('12345here67890', '12345','67890')[0];
*/

function getSubstring($source, $string_before, $string_after, $offset = 0, $includeEnvelope = false) {
   if (strlen($source)<$offset)
      return(array('text' => '', 'pos' => false)); // kind of silly, but prevents an 'Offset not contained in string' warning
   $pos1 = strpos($source, $string_before, $offset);
   $sb_len = strlen($string_before);
   if ($pos1===false) {
      $result = '';
   }
   else {
      $pos2 = strpos($source, $string_after, $pos1 + strlen($string_before));
      if ($pos2===false) {
         $result = '';
         $pos1 = false;
      }
      else {
         $result = substr($source, $pos1 + $sb_len, $pos2 - $pos1 - $sb_len);
         if ($includeEnvelope)
            $result = $string_before.$result.$string_after;
     }
   }
   return (array('text' => $result, 'pos' => $pos1));
}
```